Find the approximate base of the cumulus clouds with Lapse Rate
Okay, so I know how to calculate the base of cumulus clouds, however, this is the first time I'm seeing lapse rate in the question:
Normally I would do ((23 - 15) / 2.5) * 1000 which would give me 3200, then add the elevation, which was 3700. I figured 4,000 was the "close" answer due to lapse rate, but I was wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

Way out of my stovepipe, but don't they tell you to use 2 for the lapse rate and you used 2.5? Which would make the answer 4500.

Wow, now I feel silly. That makes perfect sense now. That was the issue.

OK, I'll post it as an answer.

The lapse rate given in the question is 2 but you used 2.5.
Substituting the proper lapse rate gives an answer of 4500.
